# xslt-v1: sum of element values defined by neighbours

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

how can I create result string "Code" + "Sum_of_Value_for_adjacent_Items_with_equal_Code"-... ? In other words, for xml below reslut should be A3-B7-A2-C13-A4.
Is it possible to achieve with xsl v1?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<MyXML>
<Item id = "1">
     <Code>A</Code> 
     <Value>2</Value> 
</Item>
<Item id = "2">
     <Code>A</Code> 
     <Value>1</Value> 
</Item>
<Item id = "3">
     <Code>B</Code> 
     <Value>7</Value> 
</Item>
<Item id = "4">
     <Code>A</Code> 
     <Value>2</Value> 
</Item>
<Item id = "5">
     <Code>C</Code> 
     <Value>8</Value> 
</Item>
<Item id = "6">
     <Code>C</Code> 
     <Value>3</Value> 
</Item> 
<Item id = "7">
     <Code>C</Code> 
     <Value>2</Value> 
</Item>     
<Item id = "8">
     <Code>A</Code> 
     <Value>4</Value> 
</Item>     
</MyXML>
```

Comment: You've tagged this XSLT 1.0, but are you definitely sure you can't use XSLT 2.0 as it would be so much easier then (with `xsl:for-each-group`). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One XSLT 1 approach for that is so called sibling recursion where you process the first `Item` and then recursively the next `following-sibling::Item[1]`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*/Item[1]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Item">
      <xsl:param name="sum" select="0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="next" select="following-sibling::Item[1]"/>
      <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$next/Code = Code">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="$next">
                  <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$sum + Value"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="concat(Code, $sum + Value, '-')"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="$next"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtr6

This shows the approach in general, to avoid a trailing `-` after the last value you need to insert an additional check or store the result in a variable and extract `substring($var, 1, string-length($var) - 1)`.